# Copy TEXT to Clipboard on Button-Click but where are the <br>

Tags: text, copy, clipboard

it works but the copy text has everything in one line. 
Does anyone knows why it does not shows them in separate lines
Thanks

```
 function copyToClipboard(element) {
 var $temp = $("<input>");
 $("body").append($temp);
 $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
 document.execCommand("copy");
 $temp.remove();
 alert("The answer has been Copied");
}

<p id="p">Hello, <br>
please <br>
copy my text  <br>
</p>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p')">Copy TEXT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `<br>` tag is not read as a new line. The fix involved finding and replacing the `<br>` tag with `\r\n`.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {

  // REPLACE <BR> AND CREATE CLEAN STRING
  var brRegex = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
  var cleanString = $(element).html().replace(brRegex,"\r\n");

  // TEMP VAR TO SELECT TEXT FROM
  var $temp = $("<textarea>");
  
  // ADD TEMP TO BODY
  $("body").append($temp);
  
  // SET TEMP VALUE
  $temp.val(cleanString);
  
  // SELECT TEMP
  $temp.select();
  
  // EXECUTE COPY
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  // REMOVE TEMP ELEMENT
  $temp.remove();
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p">Hello, <br>
please <br>
copy my text  <br>
</p>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p')"> Copy TEXT </button>
```

Comment: @NikosCorfu You are welcome! If this solved your issue could you please accept it as the answer to close the question?